# How to add text next to progress bar bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, label, progress-bar

Hi I am trying to add some text to a progress bar in bootstrap. The way I want it to look is the follow:

Java: x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-

C++ : x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-

where x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x- is the progress bar.

I have written some code but I can't seem to get the text inline with the progress bar. Any help would be useful. I am using just bootstrap.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height:500px;overflow:scroll">

                        <div class ="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4>Programming Proficiency</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="alert alert-info">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <p><h4>Java</h4><div class="progress col-md-2"></div></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix this by CSS rules on the H4 label.

[JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/A3d8g/)

Change HTML to this :

```
<h4 class="progress-label">Java</h4>
```

And CSS to that :

```
.progress-label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. You can actually use any tag in BS4, as long as you add the progress-label class to it.