# How can I place icons next to a progress bar in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, icons, progress-bar

I am trying to achieve the following result using bootstrap components:
[image]

The diamonds labeled 1 and 2 represent icons I wish to place on each side. I want them as close and properly lined up to the progress bar as possible.

I tried putting them inside and besides the bar and using floats, sadly this did not help. I hope that someone can help me out here.

```html
<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <p>1: <i class="fas fa-video my-3"></i> Maak je account</p>
    <p id="label-1" class="progress-label">text</p>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Optio dolores aperiam, ab soluta placeat sapiente beatae cupiditate voluptate tempore sed quaerat facere eum temporibus quam modi! Obcaecati, aspernatur. Sint, qui.
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <p>2: <i class="fas fa-video my-3"></i> Kies je pakket</p>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, pariatur doloribus eligendi deleniti aut adipisci aspernatur et eum minima ipsum esse? Necessitatibus natus atque quam! Laborum quia quibusdam nostrum voluptates?
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, this is without the proper library attached (which is bootstrap) I sadly didn't figure out a way to link it to the snippet. If anyone knows how: I'd greatly appreciate a tip on that matter.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried to solve this

Comment: You could have said that without downvoting you know. Also I currently cannot post it as it is a collaborative project and I don't have access to it.

I can however show you the code which is very similar to the solution I implemented for the time being: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396214/how-to-add-text-next-to-progress-bar-bootstrap 

I know it says text but I figured icons would work as well.

Comment: I didn't downvote this. Maybe if you edit the question and post the code you've attempted you will get an upvote. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Several classes of `bootstrap` is required in order to achieve your desired output, but you have to provide your code so to get a better view of your output.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/027b364b90.js"></script>



<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <span class="stars">
    <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
  </span>
  <div class="col text-center">
    Your Icon text
    <div class="progress">

      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 5%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="stars">
    <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
  </span>
</div>
```